# Permissions Issues - cannot write log files to docker-volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions, docker-volume, dbt

We're running `DBT` in Airflow on a GCP Compute Engine using Docker and `docker-compose`. In the `docker-compose.yml` file for our Airflow deployment, the DBT repo is attached as a volume:

```
webserver:
    ...
    volumes:
        - ../our-dbt-repo:/usr/local/airflow/dbt
```

Running `dbt-run` usually generates a `/logs` directory with DBT logs. However, running `dbt-run` from the docker container on the GCP machine is throwing the error `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'logs'`.

To test permissions, I ran `docker exec -it <DockerContainerID> bash` from the command line of the GCP machine (while the docker container is running) to get into the running docker container, and ran `cd /usr/local/airflow/dbt/ && touch file.txt`, and received the error: `touch: cannot touch 'file.txt': Permission denied`. So it seems clear that no files can be added to the `/dbt` folder that was added as a volume in the Docker Container, which is why the logs cannot get written.

Is there a way to give our `/dbt` volume permissions to write logs? Perhaps we can write DBT logs somewhere else (not in the container on the GCP server), that way there are no writes required in the `/dbt` volume on the container?

Comment: `--user` parameter might help

Comment: @full_steak_developer how so?

Comment: Is your mount read-only or read-write ? https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume 
Read-write is the default but maybe you've overwritten it when defining the volume. This is the syntax: `[SOURCE:]TARGET[:MODE]`

Comment: so, when I ran `ls -la` on the docker container, the uid was `1002` instead of `1000`... I had created other users on the machine, and the user I was using didn't have permissions to write the files. I used `usermod` to manually change the permissions of files and this resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi @Canovice I am facing a somewhat similar issue with the difference that I am mounting a git sidecar container, Have you managed to resolve this? If so, how